# Как сделать такой элемент меню?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такой срез как на картинке?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не знаю как сделать срез слева и справа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще как вариант, использовать `clip-path`

Пример

```css
.menu-link {  
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  clip-path: polygon(1em 0, 100% 0, calc(100% - 1em) 100%, 0 100%);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-link:hover,
.menu-link:focus,
.menu-link:active {
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="menu-link">Категория</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  transform: skewX(160deg);
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: skewX(-160deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Категория</span>
</div>
```